# Installed Laravel sanctum but faced an error during creating token

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, bearer-token

I installed the Laravel sanctum for creating token, but when I am going to create a API token I faced this error:

```
Error: Class 'App\Models\Passport\PersonalAccessToken' not found in file E:\Laravel-WebApps\Vue-CMS\vendor\laravel\sanctum\src\Guard.php on line 63
```

Even I did not install the Laravel passport.

User Model

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;
```

API Route

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user-profile', 'Admin\API\UserController@profile');
```

User Controller

```
public function profile(Request $request)
    {
        return auth('sanctum')->user();
        or 
        return auth('api')->user();
    }
```

auth.php

```
'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
```

Profile Vue

```
 mounted(){
            axios.get('/api/user-profile')
            .then( response => {
                console.log( response );
            })
            .catch( error => {
                console.log( error );
            } )
        }
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.1|^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.29",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.8",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "2.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.3",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5.8|^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
    {
        Sanctum::usePersonalAccessTokenModel(PersonalAccessToken::class);
    }
```

In the console, it always returns unauthenticated

And when I am going to create API token using tinker
it throws this above error.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my self because I found a solution

In Laravel Sanctum documentation, they added the passport class at the top so that's why I, unfortunately, added the passport class at the top. like below.

```
use App\Models\Passport\PersonalAccessToken;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;
```

When I remove this passport class my code works successfully. documentation link:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#issuing-mobile-api-tokens
[image: Here is the image of Laravel sanctum documentation]